# Ember.js: How to preserve HTML tags in a template

Tags: ember.js

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item-view">
  {{#with view.content.json}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{unbound artistName}}</td>
    <td>{{unbound price}}</td>
    <td>{{unbound primaryGenreName}}</td>
    <td>{{unbound version}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/with}}
</script>

<table>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view Em.CollectionView itemViewClass="App.ItemView" contentBinding="App.itemsController"}}
  </script>
</table>
```

The HTML table tags in the above template are stripped out using ember-1.0.pre.js. Is there a more appropriate pattern than this for outputting a table of results where there are many values?

The post [Handlebars.js: Nested templates strip “safe” HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457566/handlebars-js-nested-templates-strip-safe-html) appears relevant to the subject of preserving the tags but Ember adds its own abstraction on top of this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [ember docs](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.CollectionView.html#automaticmatchingofparentchildtagnames), I think this what you are trying to find.  You should be able to substitute a bunch of different list types in depending on your goal.

```
anUndorderedListView = Ember.CollectionView.create({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    content: ['A','B','C','D'],
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'item-view'
    })
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/PAqpG/)